# React, Babel — Nesting conditions within a JSX block doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, conditional-statements, babeljs

I have what I'd hope is a fairly normal setup for coding React with ES6 syntax, namely I am using Babel to transpile and Webpack to assemble the code.

This is how I have Babel configured (extracted from package.json)

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"loose": true}],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
},
```

When conditionally rendering content within a JSX block using React, if I do this

```
{showingVoterList && (
  {!!message && (
    <Panel header='Could not load voters' bsStyle='danger'>
        <p>{message}</p>
    </Panel>
  )}
  {!message && (
    <p>Voter list goes here</p>
  )}
)}
```

I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (53:11)

  51 | 
  52 |         {showingVoterList && (
> 53 |           {!!message && (
     |            ^
  54 |             <Panel header='Could not load voters' bsStyle='danger'>
  55 |                 <p>{message}</p>
  56 |             </Panel>
```

but if I do this, it works fine

```
{showingVoterList && !!message && (
  <Panel header='Could not load voters' bsStyle='danger'>
      <p>{message}</p>
  </Panel>
)}
{showingVoterList && !message && (
  <p>Voter list goes here</p>
)}
```

Why can't the conditions be nested?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/690). Nested conditionals get messy really quick. Perhaps do it outside `render`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have provided is not valid JavaScript inside a JSX tag.

The second brace where the error occurs is interpreted as an Object, which is why it is not expecting the token `!`;

If you wanted to keep this code inline you could convert it to use a ternary like this:

```
{showingVoterList && (
  !!message 
    ? <Panel header='Could not load voters' bsStyle='danger'>
        <p>{message}</p>
      </Panel>
    : <p>Voter list goes here</p>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks; makes perfect sense. I've refactored my code now to split out the nested stuff into other functions. Much cleaner.